# What can we say about an integral to some power in terms of an inequality?

Tags: calculus

Consider $\mid \int f dt \mid ^p$, can we bound this in terms on something like $\int \mid f\mid^p dt$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the range for $t$ and the value of $p$. The most useful in equlality of this type is $|\int_a^{b} f(t)dt|^{p} \leq \int_a^{b} |f(t)|^{p} dt (b-a)^{p-1}$ if $1<p<\infty$.

Comment: You know where I can find a proof?

Comment: @Probably I just applied Holder's inequality writing $f$ as the product $(f)(1)$.